# html5 FileReader , what kind of data readAsDataUrl function returns? is it url adress? or data itself?

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

```
function readURL(input){    
    if(input.files && input.files[0]){
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else {
        document.images[0].src = input.value || "No file selected";
    }
}
function checkSrc(){
    var src = document.getElementById('propertyImg').getAttribute('src');
    console.debug(src);
}
<input type='file' class='width70_prop' onchange="readURL(this);"></input>
<button onclick='checkSrc()'>check</button>
```

I am curious what kind of data FileReader's readAsDataUrl function returns. 
When I checked src attribute via above code, it was look like 
ridiculously giant long string(string begins something base-64 blah blah) . 
 
I am wondering that string refers file's address or file itself.
any help will be appreciated. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the file itself, but base-64 encoded. It is also known as

[Data Uris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Answer (score 3):

It's the contents of the file encoded as Base64 string, suitable for use in a URL.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader