# HTML Image source convert to unknow codes

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to send a form via javascript and php,but php returns to me lots of unknown codes in src attribute, here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '../libs/delete-post-photo.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          path: photoToDelete
        },
        success: function(returnR){
          console.log(returnR);
        }
      });
    function readURL(input) {
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
         var reader = new FileReader();

         reader.onload = function (e) {
             $('#photoTitle').attr('src', e.target.result);
         }

         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
 }

 $("#subject_photo_up").change(function(){
     readURL(this);
 });
```

Server side:

```
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
      echo $_POST['path'];
    }
```

Comment: What "unknown code" does it return?

Comment: I think that you return the image itself from php, not it's url

Comment: data:image/jpeg;base64,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

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 FileReader , what kind of data readAsDataUrl function returns? is it url adress? or data itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972110/html5-filereader-what-kind-of-data-readasdataurl-function-returns-is-it-url-a)

Comment: It just return raw data, but I need image source.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution, This is pretty simple.

```
    console.log(file.name);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not get the absolute path to the file due to security reasons. Browsers do not allow access to the file system directly to Javascript.
You can get the file name though using the `value` property.